# Hartl Chapter 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, testing, rspec

Can someone help? I'm having an issue with testing at the end of the Michael Hartl rails tutorial, chapter 6.

Here are the results of my test:

---

```
Failures:

  1) with a password that's too short 
     Failure/Error: before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `password_confirmation=' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) return value of authenticate method with invalid password 
     Failure/Error: before { @user.save }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) return value of authenticate method with invalid password 
     Failure/Error: before { @user.save }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) return value of authenticate method with valid password 
     Failure/Error: before { @user.save }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.55 seconds
30 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:81 # with a password that's too short 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:96 # return value of authenticate method with invalid password 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:95 # return value of authenticate method with invalid password 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:89 # return value of authenticate method with valid password
```

---

Here is my user_spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }
  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = "" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

    describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = "" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

   describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        expect(@user).not_to be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        expect(@user).to be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password is not present" do
    before do
      @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                       password: "", password_confirmation: "")
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
    end
  end

  describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }

   describe "with valid password" do
     it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
    end
  end
```

---

And here is my user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password

  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

---

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your blocks. You define `@user` in first `before` block and it works. But started from some line it  is broken. The problem is in excess `end`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  ... # first specs

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end # <--- THIS `end` ends main describe block. And next describe block can't use any before blocks before

describe "with a password that's too short" do
  before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
  it { should be_invalid }
end

describe "return value of authenticate method" do
  before { @user.save }
  let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }

  describe "with valid password" do
    it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
  end

  describe "with invalid password" do
    let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

    it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
    specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
  end
end
```

Comment: That solved the problem! Thanks gotva! I simply had to put that "end" at the very end.